# How to pin the search bar to tthe top of select modal - native-base - react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, select, searchbar, native-base

I need to pin the search bar to the top of my modal. Anyone havee any suggestions? I am using native-base. I need this done by today. Please help.

```
  <Select selectedValue={selected} onValueChange={val => setSelected(val)}
             
                fontSize='sm' borderColor='transparent' borderRadius='2xl'
                bg='muted.100' _dark={{ bg: 'muted.800' }}
                h={12} px={4}
                _item={{ _pressed: { bg: 'transparent', opacity: 0.8 } }}

                _actionSheetBody={{
                  ListHeaderComponent: 
                  

                  <FormControl px={3} mb={3}>


                    <Input
                      px={15}
                      py={2}
                      fontSize={16}
                      placeholder={i18n.t('search')}
                      value={searchValue}
                      _focus={{ bg: 'gray', borderColor: 'darkBlue.600' }}
                      type='text'
                      onChangeText={(value) => {
                        setSearchValue(value)
                      }}
                    />


                  </FormControl>
                }}
              >

                items.map((item, index) => <Select.Item key={index} label={item} value={item}/>)

                }
              </Select>
```

Comment: Add the example on https://snack.expo.dev/ for quick response

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside a View with style position absolute and top: 0